# Force a new value to Knockout Computed

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm building a very number/options heavy application using Knockout and on the screen I'm currently working on is pretty complex in terms of what's happening behind the scenes. The whole screen is dynamic and the options displayed are generated from an observableArray.

**Example:**

```
function backgroundTreatmentsOption(label, value, active, name) {
    var self = this;
    self.label = ko.observable(label),
    self.value = ko.isObservable(value) ? value : ko.observable(value),
    self.active = ko.isObservable(active) ? value: ko.observable(active),
    self.name = ko.observable(name)
};

self.background_treatments_options = ko.observableArray([]);

self.background_treatments_options.push(new backgroundTreatmentsOption(
    Treatment_Settings[0].Background_Treatments[0].Label_dose_H1s[0].label_text,
    sessionStorage.getItem('background_treatments_label_dose_h1s_value') || Treatment_Settings[0].Background_Treatments[0].Label_dose_H1s[0].default_value,
    false,
    'bg-label-dose-h1s'
));
```

Then to get the value (self.value) of each object (which are used later on in the app) I do the following:

```
self.background_treatments_updosed_h1s_2x_3x_4x_value = ko.computed(function () {
    var value = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.background_treatments_options().length; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            value += parseFloat(self.background_treatments_options()[i].value());
        }
    }
    return value;
});
```

---

Now this is where it gets a little complicated to explain so please let me know if there's anything that doesn't make direct sense.

Each label (self.label), when clicked toggles an 'active' state for that element in the DOM to give the visible appearance that it's switched on/off.

When the label is toggled to 'off' I need to force the related value (in this case it's `self.background_treatments_updosed_h1s_2x_3x_4x_value`) to reset to 0. I've been able to get the value of the input to reset to 0 using hacky jQuery but this doesn't reset the value at the DOM/KO level.

So my question, when the label is clicked, how can I force `self.background_treatments_updosed_h1s_2x_3x_4x_value` to become 0?

Comment: read/write in knockout computed have you tried . using this you can force a new value . cheers

Comment: How do you write back to the same value you're reading from? Or more specifically, how using the example above would I write 0 to the self.background_treatments... Variable?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:

Remove the `var value = 0;` from inside your `background_treatments_updosed_h1s_2x_3x_4x_value` computed observable.

Instead, use a variable that is scoped so that it is accessible anywhere in your ViewModel. Also, add a `subscribe` to your `label` observable so that it resets this new variable. I don't know what the entirety of your code looks like, so for instance:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var updosedValue = 0;
    self.background_treatments_updosed_h1s_2x_3x_4x_value = ko.computed(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.background_treatments_options().length; i++) {
            if (i == 1) {
                updosedValue += parseFloat(self.background_treatments_options()[i].value());
            }
        }
        return updosedValue;
    };
    function backgroundTreatmentsOption(label, value, active, name) {
        var self = this;
        self.label = ko.observable(label);
        self.value = ko.isObservable(value) ? value : ko.observable(value);
        self.active = ko.isObservable(active) ? value: ko.observable(active);
        self.name = ko.observable(name);
        self.label.subscribe(function(value) {
            if (!value)
                updosedValue = 0;
        });
    };
}
```

After reading your comments, I believe this might do the trick for the click event:

```
self.resetValueToZero = function () {
    self.computedValues([]);
    self.computedValues.push(new computedValue(
        'getValueOne:',
        0
    ));
};
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is what I'm after. I literally just want to be able to write '0' to self.background_treatmwnts.... Eg: $('label').on('click', function () { // reset to zero });

Comment: So you when you click the button, you want the text box to reset to 0.0%, but you want the label to remain as is? For instance, if the text box reads 10.0% and the label reads 10.0% and you click the button, you want the text box to go to 0.0% and the label to remain as 10.0%?

Comment: No it had to reset everything to 0, the problem was that the value was the total sum of a computed variable and was having difficiulty 'writing' 0 to that variable.